# Converting varchar into a decimal

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, data-conversion

How do I turn the values below on the left into the values in brackets? (SQL Server 2012)

```
50    (000.050)
100   (000.100)
1000  (001.000)
9999  (009.999)
20000 (020.000)
```

Comment: SQL Server 2012

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be rather easy... What have you tried yourself?

First of all: If these values are (integer) numbers, you should not store them in a string column. Any code can break easily, if there are non-numeric values among them...

You can try this:

```
DECLARE @mockup TABLE(ID INT IDENTITY,YourValue VARCHAR(100))
INSERT INTO @mockup VALUES('50'),('100'),('1000'),('9999'),('20000');

SELECT *
      ,CAST(YourValue AS DECIMAL(10,3))/1000 AS NewValue
      ,FORMAT(CAST(YourValue AS DECIMAL(10,3))/1000,'000.000') AS Formatted
FROM @mockup
```

Casting a string like `"1000"` to `DECIMAL` will get a number back. This number can be divided by 1000 to get the value needed.

If you need the format as provided, you can use `FORMAT()` on SQL-Server 2012+, but this function is known as rather slow... If this is important for you, search for other ways to format a number. There are many examples here on SO...